# How to accept remote connections to a Java WebServer

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, webserver, serversocket

## Solution

I tried many things that I found online. I tried to bind to 0.0.0.0 through the code:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000, 50, addr);
```

Which did **not** work. Then I tried the following code which **DID** end up working.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00});
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000, 50, addr);
```

If anyone can explain why this works, but the other one didn't, it would be greatly appreciated.

## Main post

I am currently trying to accept connections to a ServerSocket from my remote Amazon Web Services EC2 Server (Ubuntu 14.04, Java 1.8.0_101).

Here is the code I am working with

```
public void CallbackListen() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){

            try{
            
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5000);
              Socket conn = server.accept();
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

              OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
              int count = 0;
              
              while (true)
              {
                 count++;
                 String line = reader.readLine();
                 if (line == null)
                 {
                    System.out.println("Connection closed");
                    break;
                 }
                 System.out.println("" + count + ": " + line);
                 if (line.equals(""))
                 {
                    System.out.println("Writing response...");

                    // need to construct response bytes first
                    byte [] response = "<html><body>Hello World</body></html>".getBytes("ASCII");

                    String statusLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
                    out.write(statusLine.getBytes("ASCII"));

                    String contentLength = "Content-Length: " + response.length + "\r\n";
                    out.write(contentLength.getBytes("ASCII"));

                    // signal end of headers
                    out.write( "\r\n".getBytes("ASCII"));

                    // write actual response and flush
                    out.write(response);
                    out.flush();;
                 }
              }
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                
                
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

The purpose is to use it as a callback url for recieving POST requests with data. Right now, it is working on localhost:5000, but I cannot access it remotely. My server is accepting inbound TCP requests on port 5000. When I run a `netstat -l` command, instead of having a Local Address of *:5000, it is [::]:5000, and instead of having a Foreign Address of *:*, it is [::]:*.

How do I change my code to accept foreign requests?

Thanks,

-Justin

Comment: What rules do you have in your Security Groups? Did you open port 5000 in security groups?

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing, "My server is accepting inbound TCP requests on port 5000."

Comment: @Schwaitz what your server is accepting, as visible via `netstat`, and what the AWS firewall, known as the **Security Group** is accepting, are two totally different things. So to reiterate, did you open port 5000 in the Security Group assigned to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @MarkB, Yes, the security group is accepting inbound TCP connections on port 5000 from any IP. I have hosted web servers before (Python ones) and they have all shown *:5000 and  *.* instead of the aforementioned "[::]. It has worked for me before ON port 5000. I only set it to 5000 because they were already in my security group, and had worked. Just weren't up.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/zHeHx6e.jpg) is an image of my security group open inbound ports. As you can see, ports 5000-5020 are all open on 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Yes. I was able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things that I found online. I tried to bind to 0.0.0.0 through the code:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0");
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000, 50, addr);
```

Which did **not** work. Then I tried the following code which **DID** end up working.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00});
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(5000, 50, addr);
```